# Why $\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{\sin(z)}z$ doesn't exist?

Tags: complex-analysis

I think if we let $t=\frac1z$, then
$$\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{\sin(z)}z=\lim_{t\to0}t\sin(\frac1t)=0$$
but I don't know why in Ablowitz-Fokas Complex Variables, in "Answer to Odd-Numbered Exercises", answer is "doesn't exist"?

Comment: Hint: [Wolfram|Alpha agrees with you.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+as+z+to+infinity+of+sin(z)%2Fz)

Comment: @Emracool wolfram alpha assumes that $z$ is real.

Comment: @mrf Good point. Didn't catch that one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that $z$ and hence your $t$ is not necessarily *real*. Investigate what happens when you let $z$ approach $\infty$ along the imaginary axis.

Comment: Do you say that I let $z=iy$ and evaluate $\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{\sin(iy)}{iy}$?

Comment: @user118535 Yes, for example

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: Unlike real sine and cosine, complex sine and cosine are unbounded.

Pick two sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n=\infty$ but $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sin(a_n)/a_n$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sin(b_n)/b_n$ are different.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $\sin(ix) = i\sinh(x)$. Therefore if that limit exists then this limit too must exist: $$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sin(ix)}{ix}=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{i\sinh(x)}{ix}$$